# XSD multiple elements with same name but different types

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to write an XSD against some XML that looks (structurally wise) something like this:

```
<responses>

    <response>
        <id>foo</id>
        <values>
            <value>bar</value>
        </values>
    </response>

    <response>
        <id>asdf</id>
        <values>
            <value>
                <a>a</a>
                <b>b</b>
                <c>c</c>
            </value>
        </values>
    </response>

</responses>
```

When I try to validate (using javax APIs) it, I'm getting the following error message:

`Multiple elements with name 'response', with different types, appear in the model group`

Is it possible to write an XSD that validates multiple nodes with the same names like this?  The order in which the individual response nodes is consistent, so that part wouldn't be an issue at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the design level, the question to ask is why you wish to specify two different elements with different validity conditions, and then use their element type names to say that they are the same thing.  Do you believe that lying to the processor in this way is good design?

At the schema level:  the type to be assigned to an element is completely determined by the path from the validation root.  (If the validation starts at the document root, then in your example the type of a `response` element must be completely determined by the path `/responses/response`.  It is perfectly legal to have two elements with the same name which appear in different contexts (where 'context' is defined solely by ancestry and not by siblings); it is not allowed in XSD to have different default types for two siblings of the same name.

Comment: I don't have control of the design unfortunately, it's data coming back from a web service :(

Comment: You may not control what XML gets sent by that service, but do you not control how you work with it?  If you want to validate the data, then you might want to transform the XML from the web service into a form better suited for validation, then validate it.  If you want the schema solely for data binding purposes, transforming it first may or may not help with that, too.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now.  Transforming it could be an option.  If I can't do it without XSD alone I'll probably end up having to go that route.  Any idea if this is possible with XSD 1.1?

Comment: XSD 1.1 assertions can be used to impose arbitrary constraints, limited primarily by your ingenuity in formulating them in XPath (or in the minimum subset of XPath which XSD 1.1 processors are required to support).