# xsd - Multiple elements with same name with different types

Tags: java, soap, xsd, jaxb

I am attempting to write xsd for below soap envelop. But i says "**cos-element-consistent: Error for type '#AnonType_process'. Multiple elements with name 'calc', with different types, appear in the model group.**"

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="process">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="calc" type="wsInput"/>
        <xs:element name="calc" type="wsCalc"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="wsInput">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="fieldName" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="value" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="wsCalc">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="txnAmt" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Below is my expected soap envelop to generate in soap client.

```
<S:Envelope> 
<S:Body>
<ns2:process xmlns:ns2="http://soap.com/">
// List of calc input fields will be here
<calc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:wsInput">
            <fieldName>DATE</fieldName>
            <value>20170101</value>
         </calc>

// List of output/result fields will be here
<calc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:wsCalc">
            <txnAmt>100.00</txnAmt>
         </calc >
</ns2:process
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Please someone provide me input to achieve this type of requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You need `<xs:choice>`. Something like

```
<xs:element name="process">
  <xs:choice>
    <xs:element name="calc1" type="wsInput">
    <xs:element name="calc2" type="wsCalc">
```

Note that elements have different names because [you can't define sibling with different types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25575660/xsd-multiple-elements-with-same-name-but-different-types?rq=1)

Comment: @ ADS But i need <calc xsi:type="ns2:wsInput"> <calc xsi:type="ns2:wsCalc">. Same element name but different type, Please look above my soap envelop.

Comment: Please provide me some inputs to achieve this, i am helpless here.

Comment: @Easy2DownVoteHard2Ans you **can't** do this

Comment: Can we able to generate soap envelope as above i mentioned?

Comment: @Easy2DownVoteHard2Ans: ADS is correct, and his reference link is spot on.  In fact, your question is a duplicate of that one, and I've closed it as such.  BTW, you're fortunate to be asking a question already answered by [C. M. Sperberg-McQueen](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1477421/c-m-sperberg-mcqueen); his answers are always superb.

Comment: @ kjhughes. Noted.